# JQuery :not filter question

Tags: jquery

We can pass **:checked** or **:hidden** to **:not** filter as follows:

```
:checkbox:not(:checked)
```

Why **cannot** we pass p:hidden to :not filter as follows:

```
#something:not(p:hidden)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. If you could not, then either both paragraphs in this example would come out black or both would be blue, and my test shows that the first is blue and the second is black, which is what I would expect.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang=en>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Test</title>
<h1>Testing</h1>
<p id="something">testing</p>
<p id="else" style="display: none">testing</p>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#something:not(p:hidden)').css('color', 'blue');
$('#else:not(p:hidden)').css('color', 'blue');
$('#else').css('display', 'block');
</script>
```